# My Netgear router wont connect to the internet after installing DDWRT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dd-wrt

So i just got a Netgear WNDR4500v2 and i thought that DDWRT would be a great idea to install on my router, but now i cant connect to the internet or the GUI please help!

Comment: you really need to provide a lot more information - it sounds like you may have hosed your router.  did you do a 20/20/20 reset ?  If you plug (only) your computer into the router does it get an IP address and gateway ?

Comment: @davidgo I dont get a IP address when i plug it in to my computer i have reseted it and unplugged it, i have tried to uninstall via the update in the gui but then i some how made the gui disappear.

Comment: Update: I was able to get in the GUI but i still can't connect to the internet.

Comment: I found out what was wrong and i fixed it! Thanks to all that helped! http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=648385

Comment: @Bill Welcome to superuser, i'm glad you found an answer on your own you can answer it giving you more points (handy as you can comment) and it provides an answer to this question should any body search the question.

Answer (score 0):

The DD-WRT FAQ has some troubleshooting steps.

https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Firmware_FAQ#After_upgrading_to_DD-WRT.2C_my_Internet_doesn.27t_work_anymore.21